# Remove last bottom-border

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to remove the last bottom-border inside a div like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#containerNewBuildings border-bottom:last").css("border-bottom", "none")

});
```

But for some unknown reason it's not working. Have I done something wrong in the code?

Comment: What's your structure? Divs within the main div? A div can only have one bottom-border..

Comment: What is the border-bottom part of the query #containerNewBuildings border-bottom:last? is it a class?

Comment: I thought that I could affect other DIV that had bottom-border inside the containerNewBuildings DIV, but thats perhaps not possible!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selectors are only for DOM elements not for CSS attributes. Do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#containerNewBuildings").css("border-bottom", "none");

});
```

**EDIT**: "Yes, but I'm using several bottom-borders below some menu options, but it's just the last one I want to remove"

Answer:

```
$(".myContainerOfMenuOptions").children().last().css("border-bottom", "none");
```

Comment: Hmm, but then all will be gone!? I want some to be kept!

Comment: nope it will only modify Border Bottom. Any other borders will remain! Try it.

Comment: Yes, but I'm using several bottom-borders below some menu options, but it's just the last one I want to remove

Comment: $(".WhateverContainermenuoptions").children().last().css("border-bottom", "none");

Answer (score 1):

if you only want the last #containerNewBuilding to have no border bottom you're looking for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#containerNewBuildings:last").css("border-bottom", "none");
});
```

Comment: You're absolutely right @sajawikiko. However, I'm only working with what OP supplied.

Comment: If OP had multiple ID's on elements, the code will break and not work properly, likely (I am almost certain it wouldn't work at all) with multiple ID's: ID selector must return one and only one element - if it doesn't, behavior is I believe no longer predictable and even can freeze entire DOM in complex applications.

Comment: No, I had several classes that had bottom-borders. I just thought I could affect all class elements that hade a bottom-border that was inside the ID containerNewBuildings

Comment: YES!! You can -->

$("#myUniqueContainer").children().each(function(){
if($(this).css('border-bottom','solid'){DOSOMETHING(this);})
})

Comment: OK, but I didn't thougt that much code was needed for that in jQuery, but I will try it later

Comment: Or you can do this to reduce code: in stylesheet, make all of your border bottoms have a certain class which causes the border bottom solid, e.g. in stylesheet, put .borderbottomelems{border-bottom:solid;} , then apply that class to your desired elements, and then...

then in javascript, do this: $("#myUniqueContainer").children('.borderbottomelems'); to get all of your desired elements!

Answer (score 0):

modify your selector

form $("#containerNewBuildings border-bottom:last") to $("#containerNewBuildingst")